# About OrdinalEncoder in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

Some of my features have values such as excellent, good, average, bad and so on. Obviously they are in order. So I decided to use `OrdinalEncoder` in sklearn. I want to encode like that: excellent=0, good=1,average=2, bad=3. But I find it has encoded like this: excellent=2, good=3, bad=1, average=0.

How can I adjust the order? Does `OrdinalEncoder` has some parameters to control that?

Comment: I don't think `OrdinalEncoder` has any parameter to do that. But, you can do it on your own by creating a dictionary.

Comment: After creating a dictionary, still use OrdinalEncoder? Or other function?

Comment: And I also want to know how to encode these features which have obvious order in Python and ML?  Thank you!

Comment: No, I said make a dictionary and replace those words with numbers.

Comment: Create a dictionary: `my_dict = {'excellent':0, 'good':1, 'average':2, 'bad':3}` and replace the words: `df['feature'] = df['feature'].replace(my_dict)`

Comment: Using this dictionary, does the numbers have 'orders' in model training? For example, 0>1 means'excellent'>'good'?  Could I use target encoding to encode these features that have orders?

Comment: Yes. It has order.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4):

OrdinalEncoder does not carry a specific ordering contract by default (the current source code for sklearn appears to use np.unique) to assign the ordinal to each value. You can assign the ordering yourself by passing a 2D array (features x categories) as the `categories` parameter to the constructor. For your case, try this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
# This is the actual answer:
oe = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['excellent', 'good', 'average', 'bad']])
# Prove it
X = [['bad'], ['excellent'], ['average'], ['bad'], ['good']]
oe.fit_transform(X)
```

Resulting in:

```
array([[3.],
   [0.],
   [2.],
   [3.],
   [1.]])
```

The advice from the comments to create a dictionary instead is not a bad option either if you have a small number of known classes. `{'excellent':0, 'good':1, 'average':2, 'bad':3}` is simpler and more portable than lugging around an OrdinalEncoder object.